# wxWidgets - remove the frame around a Bitmap Button

Tags: c++, image, user-interface, button, wxwidgets

I'm just getting started with wxWidgets, so please be kind on me. 
How can i disable, that a frame appears around a Button, when the mouse enters the Button. Or is the another/easier way to make a Picture click-able ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for [wxBitmapButton](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.0/classwx_bitmap_button.html) which allows you to set different bitmaps for its different states (focused, pressed, ...).

If not, then you really need to explain more clearly what are you after.

Comment: I already tried the BitmapButton with wxBORDER_NONE. That works fine, as long as is don't hover over the Button. As soon as the mouse enters the button area, the border lights up again. But i don't want that behavier. I just want to be able to get a mouse clickt event, when i click on the image. But i don't want anything else, no reappearing boarder, no visual response.

Comment: It looks like you want a `wxStaticBitmap` but this will, of course, be confusing to the user -- `wxBitmapButton` behaviour is much more usual and you really should ask yourself why do you want to override it.